# How to integrate React Router in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to integrate Routes using React Router in Meteor Project. I have followed the Meteor React documentation but somehow its not working. Have tried with "Router" instead of "BrowserRouter" but no luck. Any suggestions on this.

**imports/startup/client/routes.js**

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import App, City , NotFound from "respective-modules";
 
export const renderRoutes = () => {
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
        <Route exact path="/city" component={City} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>;
```

**client/main.html**

```
<body>
  <div id="react-target"></div>
</body>
```

**client/main.jsx**

```
import { renderRoutes } from "/imports/startup/client/routes.js";

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById("react-target"));
});
```

But a blank page is getting appeared.

Comment: `import App, City , NotFound from "respective-modules";` looks wrong, or do you really have your components in an external npm package? Do you have any errors in the browser console? Also, can you post the App source here? I'm assuming you are testing with the `/` route, and that's what's blank, right?

Comment: I just avoided boiler plate code @ChristianFritz

Comment: Hi @ChristinaFritz, Unfortunately there is no error. Its just not rendering the renderRoutes() function. If I connect a direct component (< City /> ) shown below, its working correctly. But My requirement is Routes config.

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render( <City />, document.getElementById("react-target"));
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you are showing is correct (i.e., copied accurate from what you are running), then you just have an extra curly bracket:

```
export const renderRoutes = () => {
  <BrowserRouter>
```

needs to be either:

```
export const renderRoutes = () => 
  <BrowserRouter>
```

or

```
export const renderRoutes = () => {
  return <BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Brilliant @Christian Fritz. Spent almost  6 hours so far. Thanks for saving me from this bug. Accepting the answer right away. Cheers !

Comment: happy to help! I don't know how many times this has happened to me, too.